# different prediction values for the same ALS spark model

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have an issue with ALS recommendation model of Apache spark.
when I train my model with the same parameters and the same input data, I get different recommendations with different prediction value at each execution.

I need to know if it is normal?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is normal.

Since ALS uses Ordinary Least Squares, you might expect the solution to be unique. However, since the user-factor and factor-item matrices are initialised with random values, the solution is not unique. If these matrices were initialised with a constant, then the solution would be unique.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, how can I initialize user-factor and factor-item with constant values to get unique solution at each execution?

Comment: Implement the entire algorithm from scratch yourself! I think a more interesting question is perhaps why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Because getting different personalized recommendations in each iteration is abnormal, isn't it?

Comment: Its very unlikely that the recommendations would be different. The values will just be very marginally changed. A lot of non-deterministic algorithms are used in recommender systems. Since recommendations are subjective, not objective, thesr minor changes will be within acceptable error margins anyway. Some put a positive spin on it and say it increases the serendipity of the recommendations :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarifications